# How to Add file to Layouts folder in 14 hive Using Solution for SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

We have migrated our SharePoint Project from 2010 to 2013. All the code references have been changed with respect to 2013 solution. 
Now we need to add one html file in **C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS Location on SharePoint 2013 Server.**

i can't see any option to add file to layouts folder in VS Solution targeted for SharePoint 2013 as all files in layouts section will be deployed Under 15 hive.

I did lot of research but couldn't find solution. The only solution is to create another sharepoint Project for 2010 and add file throught that projet. But we need to have these file included in VS2013 Solution.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

It is true that **VS13** adds everything in **15** hive But you can add a `.wsp` in **14** hive too by PowerShell.

```
Install-SPSolution -Identity contoso_solution.wsp -GACDeployment -CompatibilityLevel 14
```

*MSDN* reference https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607534.aspx

So build everything in **15** hive and then use PowerShell to move into **14**